# How to divide two words that appear in navigation bar tabs , in shiny app, html?

Tags: r, string, tabs, navbar, shinyapps

I am trying to make two lines of the words that appear in each tab, in navigation bar but cannot in any way.

Here it is the pics with the words I am trying to divide in two lines.

And here is a snippet of a code in r script

```
 gene_expressions_sign_tab <- shiny::tabPanel(
      "Gene Expression",
      icon = icon("chart-line"),
      value = "Gene",
      wellPanel(
        fluidRow("etc")
```

############################################################################Adding extra info after I have been given an answer bellow
###########################################################################
And it possible to get the two words in two lines in one tab, is it possible to centre the words? the picture reveals the fact the words aren't centered.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `"Gene\nExpression"` instead of `"Gene Expression"`?

Comment: @AllanCameron yes, I have tried it and it doesn't work. This is because it is within a tabPanel function, which it isn't like tittle function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HTML` and embed `<br/>` in your titles.

```r
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(HTML("hello<br/>world")),
      tabPanel(HTML("hello<br/>again"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image]

Comment: the issue though is that the words are not centered and looks aesthetically off. is there a way to centre the words in tabs?

Comment: How would do the alignment in raw html?